# Problem in Reading JSON file and creating records in SQL

Tags: c#, json

I have difficulty in reading the following JSON format in C#,as the attributes changes inside each section.Can somebody help me on this?

```
[
{
  "Product": "P1"
  "Package": [{
               "p_make": "hy",
               "p_maketype": "1",
               "p_relation": "P111"
              },
             {
             "p_make": "hz",
             "p_maketype": "1",
             "p_relation": "P111"
             }],

},
{
  "Product": "P2",
  "Package": [{
             "p_make": "ha",
             "p_maketype": "2",
             "p_relation": "P112"
               },
             {
              "p_make": "hb",
              "p_maketype": "2",
              "p_relation": "P112"
               },
             {
             "p_make": "hc",
             "p_maketype": "2",
             "p_relation": "P112"
             } ],
}
]
```

What I am trying to achieve is read the json file and create rows in SQL.

Like the one below

```
p_make  p_maketype    p_relation  Product

hy        1            P111         P1

hz        1            P111         P1

ha        2            P112          P2

hb        2            P112          P2

hc        2            P112          P2
```

Answer (score 0):

Newtonsoft will allow you to deserialize JSON into an object.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

here is fiddle.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/7PRHEW

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"[
                            { 'Product': 'P1', 'Package': 
                               [
                                { 'p_make': 'hy', 'p_maketype': '1', 'p_relation': 'P111'},
                                { 'p_make': 'hz', 'p_maketype': '1', 'p_relation': 'P111' }
                              ]
                            },
                            { 'Product': 'P2', 'Package': 
                                 [
                                    { 'p_make': 'ha', 'p_maketype': '2', 'p_relation': 'P112'},
                                    { 'p_make': 'hb', 'p_maketype': '2', 'p_relation': 'P112'}
                                ]
                             }
                            ]";


        List<MyClass> myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(json);
        // do your inserts however you do it ADO, entitiy framework etc.

    }
}
public class MyClass
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public List<Package> Packages {get; set;}
}

public class Package
{
     public string P_make { get; set; }
     public int P_maketype { get; set; }
     public string P_relation { get; set; }
}
```